# Should I enable QoS on the main router only or access point router too?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I am using two TP-Link wireless routers. TP-Link Archer C60 acts the primary router (DHCP enabled) directly connected to ISP with QoS enabled. A second router, TP-Link WR840N is connected via ethernet to the primary router and set in access point mode (DHCP disabled). Whenever I stream Netflix HD through Chromecast on the secondary router, 75% of the pings to the router from other wirelessly connected devices would time out. No such thing happens on the main router.

I believe the secondary router should be using QoS ofthe main router but do I need to set it up as a Wireless Router with QoS enabled to avoid such problems?

Comment: I don't think this is a qos problem. They are on non-overlaping channels right?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Yes. Channels are non-overlapping.